# How to map picklist values of two different object?

Tags: process-builder, custom-object, custom-field, standard-objects, standard-field

There are two picklist fields contact_status_c and the second one is opportunity_status_c.
I want to do mapping in a way such that if field one is 'X' then second one will be 'Y'

Answer (score 1):

If there is one definite value for the 2nd field, you can have flow/apex code which updates the value of the 2nd field using if-else or switch conditions.
In case there can be multiple values for the 2nd field, look into dependent picklists.

Comment: Can you please provide me with more details?

Comment: more details around which approach?

Comment: for the flow approach.

Comment: It will include combinations of decisions and assignment logic.  You can go like if Picklist value 1 = Option1 then assign the required value to the 2nd picklist.